# URL Routing not working in .NET Virtual Directory over a WordPress site

Tags: c#, asp.net, wordpress, url-routing, virtual-directory

Lets say this is the root web, which is a WordPress PHP site:

```
www.mywebsite.com
```

I made a sub-folder at the root web into a .NET App (a working ASP.NET website)

```
www.mywebsite.com/subapp
```

The ASP.NET site "subapp" is working fine, except that the web routing is not working.

The page "~/Login.aspx" is working fine. This page has been routed to "~/Login", which is working fine as a root web, but failed in virtual directory.

This is working:

```
www.mywebsite.com/subapp/Login.aspx
```

This is not working:

```
www.mywebsite.com/subapp/Login
```

The routing is captured by WordPress and displayed a "Page not found" by wordpress.

This is the web.config of the WordPress site:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
<system.webServer>
<rewrite>
<rules>
<rule name="HTTP to HTTPS redirect" stopProcessing="true">
<match url="(.*)"/>
<conditions><add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" ignoreCase="true"/></conditions>
<action type="Redirect" redirectType="Permanent" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}"/>
</rule>
<rule name="WordPress: https://www.mywebsite.com" patternSyntax="Wildcard">
<match url="*"/>
<conditions>
<add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true"/>
<add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true"/>
</conditions>
<action type="Rewrite" url="index.php"/>
</rule></rules>
</rewrite>
</system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

This is web routing C# code of the "subapp":

```
using System.Web.Routing;

public class Global : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        RouteTable.Routes.MapPageRoute("login", "Login", "~/Login.aspx");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have solved my problem by removing the "URL Rewrite Rule" of web.config at the WordPress site become this.

This is the modified web.config which fixed the problem:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
<system.webServer>
<rewrite>
<rules>
<rule name="HTTP to HTTPS redirect" stopProcessing="true">
<match url="(.*)"/>
<conditions><add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" ignoreCase="true"/></conditions>
<action type="Redirect" redirectType="Permanent" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}"/>
</rule>
</rules>
</rewrite>
</system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

This is the original web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
<system.webServer>
<rewrite>
<rules>
<rule name="HTTP to HTTPS redirect" stopProcessing="true">
<match url="(.*)"/>
<conditions><add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" ignoreCase="true"/></conditions>
<action type="Redirect" redirectType="Permanent" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}"/>
</rule>
<rule name="WordPress: https://www.mywebsite.com" patternSyntax="Wildcard">
<match url="*"/>
<conditions>
<add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true"/>
<add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true"/>
</conditions>
<action type="Rewrite" url="index.php"/>
</rule></rules>
</rewrite>
</system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

But, however, with this edit, WordPress is not able to capture any "Page Not Found" error.

Previous, if I enter random URL at the WordPress site, it will be captured and display a beautiful "Page Not Found" page, but it only return a server default 404 page.